# How pgpool handle concurrent sql query if they are the same?

Tags: pgpool

In my case, it's possible that a lot of the same SQL query happen at some moment, so I want to ask that if this thing happens, how pgpool handle it? Will pgpool request a lot of the same querys to the backend postgresql server or it will queue all those same query and responds when just one query get finished from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Pgpool-II can cache select queries and they can be reused. You can enable this feature by setting  `memory_cache_enabled` to `true`. You can set `memqcache_method` to `shmem` or `memcached` to further fine tune caching.
See link here for detail: https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-in-memory-query-cache.html